# Getting the sibiling from a child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style `.item` when the input is checked.

```
<input>
<span class="item">
```

I can use `input:checked ~ .item {}`

But how do I get it when the item is a child of a sibling of the input:

Like this:

```
<input>
<div>
  <span class="item"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
input:checked ~ div .item {}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLQKa/

This selects the sibling `div` and then the `.item` child.

Comment: Thanks. I am a css newbie and I did not know you can compose css like that :) I'll accept after the 5 minute count.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
input:checked + div > .item
```

Where

- `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)
- `>` is the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).